# CanCanCan throwing ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError setting non existing attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I have a very simple controller that uses a service to import mobile users, this was working fine prior to rails 5 upgrade, so I m certain it's not the service code. This is my controller :

```
module Admin
  module MobileUsers
    class ImportsController < Admin::BaseController
      load_and_authorize_resource class: MobileUser

      def create
        binding.pry
        importer = ::MobileUserImportService.new(resource_params)
        success  = importer.perform
        unless success
          @error = importer.error
          render :create, status: 400
        end
      end

      private

      def resource_params
        params.permit(:file)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to execute my rspec test for create action I get this error:

```
 ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute 'file' for MobileUser.
```

This is correct, the attribute `file` is not present on mobile user, the file contains bunch of mobile users that I importing from. I do not actually need functionality on the model for this.

And the code execution doesn't even stop at `binding.pry` inside `create` method. I've looked over this link from cancancan:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Strong-Parameters

But it didn't resolve my issue, the strong params method doesn't seem to be issue here (I've tried naming the method `create_params`, `import_params`, and even tried custom_name for sanitizer, all resulted in same issue).

**Does anyone have experience with this, how to resolve it?** I mean I could try and add virtual attribute file on my `MobileUser` and hopefully that would resolve it, but it doesn't seem like a good fix.

This happened only after I've transitioned to rails 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to change `load_and_authorize_resource` to `authorize_resource` as I really don't need an actual object for create action.

Sorry if this is spamming, I thought other people could use this answer, I wasn't able to find it